# MySQL SELECT query returns one row only

Tags: c#, mysql, .net-core

I'm trying to query against my database for multiple rows but I get one only.
I'm using MySQL 8.0 server.

```
//My async method that should return all entries that
//match given query
private async Task<List<List<string>>> QueryDb_ManyEntriesAsync(string queryString)
{
   MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(queryString, _connection);
   DbDataReader data = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync();

   var content = new List<List<string>>();

   while (true) 
   {
      var tmp = new List<string>();
      for (int i = 0; i < data.FieldCount; i++)
      {
         await data.ReadAsync();
         tmp.Add(data[i].ToString());
      }
      content.Add(tmp);

      if (!await data.NextResultAsync())
         break;
   }

   await command.DisposeAsync();
   await data.DisposeAsync();

   return content;
}
```

The query is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Transactions 
WHERE user_id=1;
```

This is what my table looks like when I run the query from MySQL Workbench:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkUBs.png

But I only get the last row when I use my C# method. I.e. `await data.NextResultAsync()` returns false after first for loop iteration.

Comment: `ReadAsync` reads the whole row. You're calling it for each field in the row so you're actually stepping down diagonally. That is, you're getting `transaction_id` from the first row, `user_id` from the second row, `is_spent` from the third row, and `ReadAsync` returns false after that (not sure how `data[i]` behaves after you've exhausted rows; MySql.Data may be different from other providers).

Comment: (and if you're using `async` with MySQL, [MySqlConnector](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/) is better.)

Comment: @madreflection thank you, that solved my issue.